# WCF Client tester and clientcredentials

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

Trying to access my service with WCF tester... but I get an error.
The username is not provided. Specify username in ClientCredentials.

How can I specify the username?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. If you defined a service secured with username and password you can't test it in WCF test client because this configuration is not supported ([check not supported features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx)).